# Receiving HTTP 500 with python requests

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I'm receiving the following error in the code below, when I try to submit the json:

```
500 Internal Server Error
{"code":"500","error":"invalid character 'o' in literal true (expecting 'r')","message"
```

I've looked in other sources but did'nt find nothing about. Someone can help me with .

Thanks in advance

```
import requests

val = {"token": "90467e25e2c5bbf6476310f9aeb1d005a73ecea5",
"email": "jaycops@gmail.com",
"answer": [{"NU_INSCRICAO": "160000000001", "NOTA_FINAL": 623.3},
{"NU_INSCRICAO": "160000000002", "NOTA_FINAL": 567.2},
{"NU_INSCRICAO": "160000000003", "NOTA_FINAL": 403.1} ]}
r = requests.post("https://api.codenation.com.br/v1/user/acceleration/data-science/challenge/enem-1/submit", data=val)
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: to submit `json` you should write`r = requests.post(url, json=val)`, not `data=val`

Comment: It works, thank you !